# How to factor polynomials by hand?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, factoring

Is there a good approach for factoring polynomials by hand (e.g. if you're in an interview situation without access to a computer)?

For example $1−4z+5z^2−2z^3$?

Comment: i think it is $z=1$

Comment: Check with $$z=1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asked to factor a cubic function by hand, you can be fairly sure there is a rational root. In this case, there are only $4$ options to check $(\pm1, \pm2)$. See [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) if this is alien.

And once you have a quadratic, you should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Rational root theorem is nice. Was able to reduce the polynomial to $(1-z)^2(1 - 2z)$ this way (along with polynomial long division)